# How to pass HTTP header information to a SonarQube Server running behind a Proxy?

Tags: iis, sonarqube, reverse-proxy

We have a `SonarQube Server` running behind `IIS` which is configured as a `reverse proxy` and we are trying to implement `SSO` for SonarQube by `delegating user authentication` to IIS. Now SonarQube is expecting `HTTP header` information related to authenticated users.

1. Where can we find those HTTP header information in IIS?
2. How do we pass them to `SonarQube`?

Expected HTTP Headers in SonarQube.

- X-Forwarded-Login
- X-Forwarded-Name
- X-Forwarded-Groups

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!:)